# Android Touch-free gesture recognition application Error

Tags: android, gesture-recognition

We are building an android application on touch free gesture recognition .

**
*Summary of CODE :

> By the code we are trying to change the text in the textfield via hand
>   Swipes. When the user  swipes his hand from right to left , the text
>   should change to Left ....and So on. When we run the app we get below
>   error, please help us resolve it.*

**

I have read manny similar errors related to my error none of them could solve mine.

Please Help

We are getting the following error:

```
04-14 00:05:39.393: E/AndroidRuntime(333): FATAL EXCEPTION: main   04-14 00:05:39.393: E/AndroidRuntime(333): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity  ComponentInfo{com.grex/com.grex.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.grex.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.grex-1.apk]
04-14 00:05:39.393: E/AndroidRuntime(333): at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
04-14 00:05:39.393: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
04-14 00:05:39.393: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117) 
04-14 00:05:39.393: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-14 00:05:39.393: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
04-14 00:05:39.393: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-14 00:05:39.393: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683) 
04-14 00:05:39.393: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
04-14 00:05:39.393: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-14 00:05:39.393: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-14 00:05:39.393: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-14 00:05:39.393: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
04-14 00:05:39.393: E/AndroidRuntime(333): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.grex.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.grex-1.apk]
04-14 00:05:39.393: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
04-14 00:05:39.393: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
04-14 00:05:39.393: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
04-14 00:05:39.393: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
04-14 00:05:39.393: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
```

Can anyone sugesst ways by vch we can fix this problem

Main Activity :

```
package com.grex;

//import com.grex.R; import com.nanocritical.nanogest.Nanogest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import com.nanocritical.nanogest.Nanogest;
import com.nanocritical.nanogest.Nanogest.Gesture;
import com.nanocritical.nanogest.Nanogest;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Nanogest.GestureListener {
    private Nanogest ngest;
    EditText et= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Button r= (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnResume);
    Button p= (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnPause);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            ngest = new Nanogest(this, this, null);
            et.getText().toString();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        try{
            super.onResume();
            ngest.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        try{
            super.onPause();
            ngest.stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onGesture(Nanogest.Gesture gesture, double timestamp) {
        try{
            switch (gesture) {
            case SWIPE_LEFT:
                onLeft();
                break;
            case SWIPE_RIGHT:
                onRight();
                break;
            case SWIPE_UP:
                onUp();
                break;
            case SWIPE_DOWN:
                onDown();
                break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void onDown() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            et.setText(R.string.down);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void onUp() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            et.setText(R.string.up);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void onRight() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            et.setText(R.string.right);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void onLeft() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            et.setText(R.string.left);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest file :

> ```
> <uses-sdk
>     android:minSdkVersion="10"
>     android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
>
> <application
>     android:allowBackup="true"
>     android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
>     android:label="@string/app_name"
>     android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:debuggable="true">
>     <activity
>         android:name="com.grex.MainActivity"
>         android:label="@string/app_name" >
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
> </application>
> ```

Comment: It would help if you posted the key bits of code (say, the class top and onCreate for the Activity) and the manifest.

Comment: Post your manifest file and MainActivity onCreate.

Comment: i have edited and mentioned in it the manifest.xml and main activity

Comment: Did you modify your code as answered by @Neil Townsend?

Comment: Yes i have done the changes ....  extra small error has poped up saying : the et cannot be resolved

Answer (score 0):

The lines:

```
EditText et= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
Button r= (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnResume);
Button p= (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnPause);
```

Should be split into two phase:

1. Declaration - same place as now:

   ```
   EditText et = null;
   Button   r  = null;
   Button   p  = null;
   ```
2. Instantation - in `onCreate()`, after `setContentView`

   ```
   et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
   r  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnResume);
   p  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnPause);
   ```

Comment: ps. It would speed up getting answers if you formatted the code so it was easy to read before submitting - I spent about 10 minutes re-formatting your code before I could work out what was going on!

Comment: srry neil for the editing trouble... i have done the changes that you told but now the code is giving error - it is unable to locate et variable in the onDown() , onUp(), onLeft() and onRight(). The error says : et cannot be resolved.

Comment: Is there error exactly the same? Could you update the code and the error in the question please?